# Date change detection on application start up - Android

Tags: android, date, android-intent, alarmmanager

I am new to Android programming and face a challenge that probably can be solved in seconds on this forum.

I am trying to figure out how to enable an application during start up to detect whether the date has changed since it's last boot.

When the date has changed, I intend to change the value in the textview. However if it hasn't,  the textview wont change. - I know how to create this function however stuck on the date change problem?

I have read on alarmmanager however not sure this is required as it doesn't need to happen at the specific time only during boot up.

Any advise would be appreciated.

Thanks,

p.s I am creating a basic quote application and want to include a quote of the day page. In order to do this, I need to know whether the date has changed in order for the application to change the quote

Comment: i don't understand the question

Comment: I am creating a basic quote application and want to include a quote of the day page. In order to do this, I need to know whether the date has changed in order for the application to change the quote, I hope this makes sense

Comment: yes, it does. you probably can store the day (DAY_OF_YEAR in Calendar) and year in SharedPreferences, and compare the values during Activity start up

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you will need is this:
A [`SharedPreference`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) with a long value describing the last date.
A [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html).

When your Activity starts (in the `onCreate()` Method seems like a good place for this) you can get a new `Calendar`. It will have the current date, and you can extract the day:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int thisDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR); //You can chose something else to compare too, such as DATE..
long todayMillis = c.getTimeInMillis(); //We might need this a bit later.
```

You then read the possibly saved value from last time and set the calendar to this value, then compare this with today:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
long last = prefs.getLong("date", 0); //If we don't have a saved value, use 0.
c.setTimeInMillis(last);
int lastDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);

if( last==0 || lastDay != thisDay ){
    //New day, update TextView and preference:
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
    edit.putLong("date", todayMillis);
    edit.commit();
}
```

Comment: in the super unlikely event someone hasn't viewed this app since the previous year and happens to open it on the same day of the year it would break this logic :) the year should be stored also for that ridiculous case :P (sorry.. had to haha)

Comment: @dymmeh, that is correct and I thought about including something about that, but it all depends on how the "quote of the day" should work, if there is 365 (366?) quotes, one for each day in the year, that is not a problem. Otherwise, one could possibly calculate the amount of days passed since a certain day and compare those values.

Comment: Very true if the quotes never change. I was expecting him to be fetching them from a server but I guess I was assuming too much.

Comment: I am using a pre-complied SQLite Database which holds all the appropriate values. So in a very unlikely circumstance, this could occur.

Comment: How would I go about saving the date in sharedpreference please?

Comment: @user983965: Sorry, forgot that part, it is added now :)

Comment: You should always force a store on the first run else lastDay and thisDay will always match as they are both grabbing the latest date. Easiest fix is to change the default from System.currentTimeMillis to -1

Comment: wont work. loads current time in last, and never stores it in shared preferences because its equal to thisday. better use sth like this: long last = prefs.getLong("date", 0);

Comment: I have corrected the example according to your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Do that when the app starts:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)

if (prefs.getBoolean("firstLaunch", true))
{
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("firstLaunch", false);
    editor.putInt("date", new Date().getTime());
    editor.commit();
}
else
{
    if (new Date().getTime() != prefs.getInt("date", 0))
    {
            // Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: this will not work. getTime is millis, and changes all the time.

Comment: Yeah I made that quickly. Check the Android javadoc to find how to use Date().